# Badge on Menu Item On Shopping Cart

Tags: android

**Hello team. I'm trying to create one Badge Counter on Menu Item on shopping cart.**
**But i get an error.**
**Error is: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference**
**Below I give you my code:**
**My code for drawable badge_shape.xml is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
    <corners android:radius="1000dp" />

</shape>
```

**My code for menu item is:**

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_cart"
        android:title="Cart"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/cart_action_item"/>

</menu>
```

**My code in xml is:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cart"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cart_badge_text_view"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_shape"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

**My code in activity is:**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.cart);
        View actionView = menuItem.getActionView();

        TextView cartBadgeTextView = (TextView)actionView.findViewById(R.id.cart_badge_text_view);


        cartBadgeTextView.setText("2");


        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if(id == R.id.cart){

            Intent intent = new Intent(CoffeeDetails.this, CartActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Check that `View actionView` is null

Comment: @TDIScott what do you mean?

Comment: Your error is NPE when trying to find the ID of cartBadgeTextView. So im betting your actionView is null. Drop a break point and have a check.